# How do I call a modal in a php code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

what I want to do is: I have a login system and when the email and password match, on the screen to show a modal that is declared in the same file.
For some reason it is not working. The php code works.

Part of php code:

```
    if(password_verify($upass, $row['password']))
    {
        /*$_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['id'];*/
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('Modal').showModal();</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "<div><center>Ati gresit email-ul sau parola!</center><br></div>";
    }
```

The modat inside the html tag:

```
    <div id="Modal" class="modal fade" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel" style="text-align: center;">You have been succesfully registered !</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn center-block" data-dismiss="modal">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't. A modal is a client-side effect. PHP runs on the server side. You *can* use PHP to include or not include HTML for your modal. Also, in your sample code above, you have both PHP and HTML, without any PHP opening (`<?php`) or closing (`?>`) tags. That's going to result in a syntax error if it's in PHP, or simply unexecuted code if it's in HTML.

Comment: But can I do it with a javascript ?

Comment: It's not working, because `document.getElementById('Modal').showModal();` most likely will be executed before doc is ready

Comment: @StelianSavca Sure, but that's not the question you asked, and it would be too broad unless you narrow it down a bit. Please read about [ask] questions here.

Comment: showModal is not supported by all browsers and showModalDialog has been deprecated. Your best bet is to use jquery, jquery ui and a blocker or dialog plugin. There are a lot of them to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ! I will try something with jsModal.